# Load sql from file and create a view of it in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, file, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having a problem with sql file that is saved in my pc. What i really is that i can create a view of that sql file that people can add extra tables to it but core will be always taken from my file. I have created a simple file and can load it to SQL Developer using `define @"C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\stock.sql"`
However,  I don't know how to work with it or create a view of it.
Tried a simple way:

```
create view  VW_MINE AS
select * 
from
( @"C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\stock.sql") X;
```

But getting an error `Invalid table name`

How can i work with that loaded SQL from file?

Comment: show us what is in 'stock.sql' file

Comment: if 'stock.sql' was delimited data, say, CSV, you could create an external table mapped to that file, and then query that. generally, when you get a .SQL file you either, open it in SQLDev, or you say @ @C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\stock.sql in a worksheet and execute with F5

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried with SQL developer, but this definitely works in SQL* Plus.

```
/*contents of mysqlfile.sql */
select * from hr.employees
```

---

```
DECLARE
  sql_file VARCHAR2(32767) := '
@@C:\Users\kaushik\Desktop\stock.sql  
';
--read the whole contents of the file into
--a variable. mysqlfile.sql cannot contain an "@" in itself. 
--the @@ expression must be in a separate line
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace view myview as ' || sql_file; --execute it dynamically.
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, but i does not work. If i put in varchar variable sql statement then it works, otherwise it shows "Missing SELECT statement"